# Show Fragment when Going Back from Action Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an app that has a main activity that has an action bar with a menu drawer. When an item from the drawer is selected, the fragment in the main activity is updated. There is a fragment that shows a new activity when a row is selected. I am trying to navigate up from that new activity using the action bar. I have it working but it loads the main activity with it's default fragment instead of the fragment that was previously displayed. Should I use onSaveInstanceState?

This is in my new activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

In my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".AutoBenefits"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

MainActivity

```
package kyfb.android.kyfb.com.kyfb;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private  CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0E4D8B")));

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[11], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(11, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[12], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(12, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[13], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(13, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[14], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(14, -1)));

        // recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and set it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ActionAlertsFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AgNewsFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MarketUpdatesFragment();
                break;
            case  3:
                fragment = new ToursFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new KFBMagFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new BenefitsFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // handle action bar actions click
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // pass any configuration changes to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fragments are all on the back stack already, just call to pop the back stack in the fragment manager instead of navigating up.

Example:

```
case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
```

Changes to:

```
case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                return true;
```

Also:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

to

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackstack(null).commit();
```

Comment: I'm new to Android. How would I do that?

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Comment: When I use that, pressing the app icon on the action bar does nothing.

Comment: You can use the popBackStackImmediate, but if they don't work it appears the fragments are not added to the backstack when you commit them. So this approach will most likely work incorrectly.